# Where to define a one-shot constant for most efficient code?

Tags: c++, performance

Which variant is most efficient, and why? Or will they get optimized to the same code?

```
char inplace(int i) {
    // [some check if 0<=i<=2 here]
    return "azS"[i];
}

char infunc(int i) {
    const char s[] = "azS";
    // [some check if 0<=i<sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0])-1 here]
    return s[i];
}

const char s[] = "azS";
char inglobals(int i) {
    // [some check if 0<=i<sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0])-1 here]
    return s[i];
}
```

Please don't rant about how premature optimization is evil, this is just irresistible curiosity inherent for a born C++'er ;)

Comment: The born C++er should learn to read assembly so she can try and see the differences (if any!) for herself!

Comment: ... and what about `return 'a' + i`?

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer because I don't know for sure, but I would expect that constant folding would transform the latter two into the first one fairly early in the optimisation process.

Comment: @akavel: There is no "why" part. The language doesn't mandate the details of its implementation. All three pieces of code behave the same (with the exception of the global in the third case), so they may all be implemented in any (possibly identical) way.

Comment: @KerrekSB: ah, good one :D I'll change the code sample to avoid this solution. And yes, I know that for any 3 chars we can still easily find a series - may I leave it as is now and not change further to 100 chars (to avoid any chance of a polynomial answer)? ;P As to assembly, it wouldn't answer the "why?" part.

Comment: @KerrekSB: would you mind moving your comment into an Answer?

Comment: Gcc 4.6.1 emits [this assembly](http://pastebin.com/nG8QkSCa) for the code in OP.

Comment: FWIW another possibility is `const char *const s = "azS"; /* check for 0 <= i < strlen(s) */ return s[i];`, and see how the optimizer does with that. Perhaps a big ask, but it might eliminate `strlen` of a known string. Also consider `switch` :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: `switch` is what I actually plan to choose, as the `int` is really an `enum`, and that feels more explicit. But oh, the burning curiosity, I just *had* to ask ;) and thanks for the strlen (non-)joke ;)

Answer (score 2):

I just compiled and disassembled your code. `inplace` and `inglobals` are identical. This is very intuitive: the compiler can store the const string in the `.rodata` section.

Weirdly, gcc produces quite a lot of code for `infunc` (see below), probably because you "insist" on having `s` on the stack. Defining `s` as `static` makes `infunc` produce the same code as `inplace` and `inglobals`.

```
0000000000000010 :
  10:   48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
  14:   48 63 ff                movslq %edi,%rdi
  17:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
  1e:   00 00 
  20:   48 89 44 24 08          mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
  25:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  27:   c7 04 24 61 7a 53 00    movl   $0x537a61,(%rsp)
  2e:   0f b6 04 3c             movzbl (%rsp,%rdi,1),%eax
  32:   48 8b 54 24 08          mov    0x8(%rsp),%rdx
  37:   64 48 33 14 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rdx
  3e:   00 00 
  40:   75 05                   jne    47 
  42:   48 83 c4 18             add    $0x18,%rsp
  46:   c3                      retq   
  47:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  4c
```

**EDIT**

The location `%fs:0x28` is related to GCC's stack protector. Disabling it give the following code:

```
0000000000000010 :
  10:   48 63 ff                movslq %edi,%rdi
  13:   c7 44 24 f0 61 7a 53    movl   $0x537a61,-0x10(%rsp)
  1a:   00 
  1b:   0f b6 44 3c f0          movzbl -0x10(%rsp,%rdi,1),%eax
  20:   c3                      retq
```

So, in this case, GCC chose to store your string inline with the code and copy it on the stack during execution. I would argue this is very efficient, since your processor's cache is already filled with the string, so no memory access occurs.

**EDIT**

To sum up, all three versions are equivalent. Nevertheless, depending on your compiler implementation, one may turn out to be more efficient than the other. For GCC, `infunc` seems more efficient for short strings, as the string is fetched along with the instructions. For larger strings, I would use `inplace` or `inglobals`.

Comment: argh, I'm used to Intel syntax, never took enough time to learn AT&T :/ would case 2 (infunc) be sure faster for small strings? probably that'd need benchmarking now... and if yes, then why wouldn't case 1 (inplace) be optimized to stack too? Thanks a lot for your answer and all this effort!

Comment: Indeed, to be sure that `infunc` is faster, benchmarking would be needed. I guess this is not trivial: its advantage would only show if the string is not already in cache, i.e., you would have to flush the cache before every call, but not measure flushing in your benchmark. As for `inplace`, you did not tell the compiler to create a local variable. I think it would be against the "spirit" of C to have the compiler do something it is not told to.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the compiler would produce the same for 1 and 3, and might produce the same for 2 (depending slightly on whether it realised it could get away with not actually copying the data onto the stack). I'm also assuming this isn't in a header or class somewhere, which would make a lot of difference (I know your code doesn't look like it is, but I'm just being cautious).

In general, unless optimisation proved otherwise, I'd go for minimising the scope of a declaration (which rules out 3). And between 1 and 2 the chances of going wrong if you change the contents of the string are much higher for 1.

Which leaves me suggesting that it is likely to make no difference in the generated code, but option 2 is a lot lot better than the other 2.

Comment: Hm, interesting; I didn't think about implications with regard to changes in the contents of the string. I'm now thus also starting to wonder if inplace string (case 1) is actually by definition `const` or not. Still, looking at user1202136's answer, IIUC gcc assumes it is `const` at least in this case.